# Подсчитать и вывести на экран количество цифр и их сумму

Tags: visual-basic

Нужно было написать вот такую программу:

> Дано целое число n, используя операции получения остатка от деления и от деления на цело, подсчитать и вывести на экран количество цифр и их сумму.

Я написал эту программму, но она работает со сбоями. То есть иногда правильно отвечает, а иногда нет. Помогите найти ошибку в программе. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

**QBasic**

```
CLS
DIM s,k,n AS INTEGER
INPUT "Введите целое число", n
k=0: s=0
DO WHILE n > 0
k=k+1
s=s+( n MOD 10 )
n=n/10
LOOP
k=k+1
s=s+( n MOD 10 )
PRINT "Количество цифр числа", k
PRINT "Сумма цифр числа", s
```

Comment: А с каким числом работает неправильно? (отрицательные?)

Кстати, вы могли бы сделать цикл просто по `while n > 0` (и выкинуть код после цикла).

Comment: Нет не только с отрицательными. С некоторыми положительными тоже.

Comment: Хотя возможно у меня Бэсик кривой скачан, но маловероятно.

Comment: @Влад Алексеев: какими?

Comment: @VladD: Ошибка с отрицательными, вообще какие-то не такие значения выдает. А с положительными любыми дает сумму правильную, а вот количество цифр на 1 больше.

Comment: @Влад Алексеев: С отрицательными числами mod работает не так, поэтому если число отрицательное, просто поменяйте знак. Если количество цифр всё время на 1 больше, думаю, вы сами знаете, что делать.

Comment: @VladD
Я ошибался....(
Число 12 (кол-во 3, сумма 3)
Число 15 (кол-во 3, сумма 7)
Число 35 (кол-во 3, сумма 9)
Число 253 (кол-во 4, сумма 10)
Число 347 (кол-во 4, сумма 16)
Число 658 (кол-во 5, сумма 22)
Вот некоторые примеры

Answer (score 2):

Используйте операцию целочисленного деления \ вместо /. Бейсик слишком умный и округляет как правильно (к ближайшему четному в случае сомнений), а не как надо. Ну и финальный k = k + 1 не нужен - все цифры уже учтены.